A good reference for irreducible decomposition like $(2,1)\otimes (1,2)=(1,1)_A \oplus (3,1)_S$?
M. Srednicki says in the book "Quantum Field Theory" on page 211 that:

I would really appreciate if someone could introduce me a good reference for understanding the irreducible decomposition of representations like $2\otimes 2=1_A \oplus 3_S$. Where can I find and learn them well?

This is covered in e.g. Georgi's 'Lie Algebras in Particle Physics'.

Here, but you learned about it in basic QM addition of spins: you are simply writing it in representation dimensionality formulas, instead of spin...

Linked.
